# Garbage disposal always on when plugged in (sparks seen on outlet at every connection)

Tags: garbage-disposal

I had to replace my leaking faucet yesterday.  In the process, a handyman came to help extract the undermount ring under the faucet, as it was severely stuck, and could not be twisted out after the screws were removed.  The previous installer applied pipe dope on it, which made it horribly impossible to twist the ring out.

I did unplug the connections for the garbage disposal and the dish washer before the old faucet removal and new faucet installation.

The handyman took hours to remove the ring with all sorts of tools.

He left after he removed the ring and removed the entire old faucet.

After I installed the new faucet, I plugged in the connection for my garbage disposal.

There’re sparks on the outlet every time I try to connect the garbage disposal, and the garbage disposal keeps running.  Also, the switch to turn the garbage disposal on and off stopped working.

Prior to the faucet removal and installation, my garbage disposal was working fine.

Please kindly advise.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Are you positive you plugged the disposal into the exact same outlet? Often only one of the two outlets on a duplex plug under the sink is wired to the disposal. You might have plugged it into a plug that is always on, which would explain the spark when plugging it in

Comment: The sparks op is seeing when plugging in the disposal? Is this just the normal action from plugging in an appliance that is in the on position?   +1 for this answer